# How to send angularjs $http GET request with body

Tags: angularjs, http

I know a GET request shouldn't have a body, but unfortunately when writing the server I didn't know that, and I am not allowed to change it. The server(Node.js) expects the get request to contain a body with a parameter. When searching for the issue I have seen a few answers mention that it is possible but none said how.
I have tried to send it this way with no success:

```
$http.get('http://localhost:3000/foo/bar',{
    data: {'foo':bar},
    headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json;charset=utf-8'}
})
```

Thanks!

Comment: Deprecate the existing API, add a new, correct one without body, and use the new one.

Answer (score 0):

From the Docs:

> The [XMLHttpRequest](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest) method `send()`, sends the request to the server.
>
> If the request method is GET or HEAD, the body parameter is ignored and the request body is set to `null`.

Since the `$http.get` method wraps the [XHR.send()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/send) method, it can't send a body with its request.

For more information, see

- [MDN Web API Reference - XHR send()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/send)